# Knit each RMarkdown file inside a given folder

Tags: r, loops, r-markdown

I have a folder with several R Markdown (.Rmd) files.  Is there a way to automatically Knit each file sequentially?

Currently I have to open a file, click Knit (takes several minutes to run), close, repeat for next file...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `rmarkdown::render` function in a loop. Here I have used `map()` from `{purrr}` package instead of an explicit for-loop.

Now suppose I have two rmd files inside of a directory `multiple_rmd`

```
+---multiple_rmd
|       rmarkdown_file_01.Rmd
|       rmarkdown_file_02.Rmd
```

Now to render them in a loop, collect the file paths (here I have used `list.files` function which returns the relative file paths) and pass the file paths of those rmd files to `render` function.

```r
rmd_files <- list.files(path = "multiple_rmd/", full.names = TRUE)
rmd_files

# [1] "multiple_rmd/rmarkdown_file_01.Rmd"
# [2] "multiple_rmd/rmarkdown_file_02.Rmd"

purrr::map(.x = rmd_files, 
           .f = ~rmarkdown::render(.x, output_dir = "multiple_rmd/"))
```

Now the rendered output files will be found in the `multiple_rmd` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
purrr::map(list.files(pattern = "\\.Rmd$"), ~rmarkdown::render(.x))
```